# Advice on Old Art

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a picture of an old print of a painting I found in my attic. Is there a site where I might ask if anyone can help me identify when it was made or who the artist might be? Or at least give ideas on how to determine these things? I considered photography, but couldn't for sure tell if that would be on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately we do not yet have such a site. Our Arts & Crafts site is more directed at homemade items, so identification and general art appreciation are not within the scope of that site.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any connection between it and your family history, you may want to post it in a question at the [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com), to explore that connection.

G&FH SE often gets old photos, old handwriting, and occasionally old paintings (usually portraits) to try and make sense of.  As long as there is a connection to family history such questions are on-topic there.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. Left there by the previous owner and I just bought the house. Maybe it had a connection to their family, but I know little about them. Good idea though.